# How can I make cygwin commands a priority over built in windows commands?

Tags: windows, powershell, cygwin

If I run ls in powershell the windows built in ls function is run.

how can I make cygwin ls run instead?

I've tried moving cygwin/bin to top begin system path variable, but that didn't work.

is this normal?

Comment: Can you even run cygwin commands in PowerShell? I though cygwin had its own shell.

Comment: it does have it's own shell but since the commands are all EXEs you can run them, and it's pretty smooth (add the cygwin/bin dir to your system path) I solved this by removing the powershell "ls" alias

Comment: ls was the only command I really needed so I can do ls --color :)

Answer (score 0):

In powershell, 'ls' is an alias. The simplest way to remove it is to add one of the following to your `$PSPROFILE`:

```
Remove-Item Alias:\ls
```

Alternatively, you can replace it with:

```
Set-Alias -Name:"ls" -Value:"ls.exe" -Option:Allscope
```

Just remember that powershell aliases cannot include arguments. If you need an argument, create a function first:

```
# The --% Is a powershell3+ feature to say "don't parse the rest of this line"
function lsFunc { ls.exe --% --color }
Set-Alias -Name:"ls" -Value:lsFunc -Option:AllScope
```